# messages notification in javascript

Tags: javascript, macos, automation

I would like to ask how the Messages Event Handler Suit Yosemite's javascript automation works. Actually, Is it possible to write a script that runs when an particular buddy becomes online? I would like to achieve a notification system for that event.

The suite contains an event `buddyBecameAvailable`, but I can't find out how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

axios.get('Route path

```js
//axios.get('/system/admin/notifications/allNotify').then(function(response){



      //let Notification =response.data
      let Notification = {Message:"recharge Successful",Time:2}
    var current=moment(new Date());

      var text = "<p>";
      var i;
      for (i in Notification) {
        if(i%2==0){
          text += "<li>"+"<i class=\"fa fa-circle-o mr-3 font-success\" > </i>"+Notification[i]["offerTitle"]+"  "+"<span class=\"pull-right\">"+current.diff(moment(Notification[i]["createdAt"]), 'minutes')+"</span>"+"min"+"</li>";
        }
        else
        {
          text += "<li>"+"<i class=\"fa fa-circle-o mr-3 font-primary\" > </i>"+Notification[i]["offerTitle"]+"  "+"<span class=\"pull-right\">"+current.diff(moment(Notification[i]["createdAt"]), 'minutes')+"</span>"+"min"+"</li>";
        }
      }
      text += "</p>";
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;

   // })
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="mb-0" id="demo"> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

').then(function(response){

```
  let Notification =response.data
var current=moment(new Date());

  var text = "<p>";
  var i;
  for (i in Notification) {
    if(i%2==0){
      text += "<li>"+"<i class=\"fa fa-circle-o mr-3 font-success\" > </i>"+Notification[i]["offerTitle"]+"  "+"<span class=\"pull-right\">"+current.diff(moment(Notification[i]["createdAt"]), 'minutes')+"</span>"+"min"+"</li>";
    }
    else
    {
      text += "<li>"+"<i class=\"fa fa-circle-o mr-3 font-primary\" > </i>"+Notification[i]["offerTitle"]+"  "+"<span class=\"pull-right\">"+current.diff(moment(Notification[i]["createdAt"]), 'minutes')+"</span>"+"min"+"</li>";
    }
  }
  text += "</p>";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;

})`enter code here`
```